# Returning false for a if / else check

Tags: javascript, php, if-statement

Sometimes you need to check if something is set or not, then you perform an operation. Sometimes there are many of these checks and I hate the indentation that is causes.

To minimize the nesting, I always check the opposite and `return` and then continue on the same indentation.

For instance, say the following

```
if (user.isOwner)
{
    // Do some operation
    // Set a value $accepted to true or false

    if ($accepted)
    {
        // Do more operation
        // And so on
    }
}
```

Instead, I write the above code as

```
if ( ! user.isOwner) return;

// Do some operation
// Set a value $accepted to true or false

if ( ! $accepted) return;

// Do more operation
// And so on
```

Could this ever lead to any problem? The function above when called, is not expected to return any result (i.e. I call is as `doThisForMe()`). My coding here is done in PHP and Javascript. I don't know if this question would be language dependent.

Comment: No problems here, you can `return True` or whatever value you wish too. But of course anything further inside the function is 'skipped'. This is language independent so long as the language permits multiple exit points from a function.

Comment: javascript is client-side, just keep that in mind - if your javascript  is meant to ensure security (such as if the person is the owner) just know that it doesn't do anything that can't be bypassed by someone with minimal development skills.

Comment: @OllieFord, okay great! Good to know that it does not cause any problem.

Comment: @skrilled, good point! Was not even thinking about this!

Comment: This looks like it could be abstracted using an Option/Maybe pattern. That way you can use composition, as opposed to procedural code.

Comment: [Dijkstra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_programming#Early_exit) wouldn't be happy, but I think there's more benefit to reducing nesting in modern languages than observing archaic 50 year old rules about single-exit points to functions. Take a read over the concept of structured programming, because that's where this path leads.

Comment: @spender There's benefits to each style, for sure. I find a single exit more readable if the function is not procedural, actually computes some value and returns it. If it's procedural then yeah - get out when done.

Comment: I think this is good practice. Minimising the use of nested if statements is always good for code readability and length. You can put your "do more operation" sections into separate functions as well and return procedurally through the execution when things go well or wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if-elseif-else` statements stop doing comparisons as soon as it finds one that's true. `if-if-if` does every comparison. The first is more efficient.

In your case, or in cases where control will leave the method (exceptions), there is no difference between doing multiple if statements and doing `if-elseif-else` statements.

However, it's best practice to use `if-elseif-else` anyhow. Suppose you change your code such that you don't do a return in every if block. Then, to remain efficient, you'd also have to change to an `if-elseif-else` idiom. Having it be `if-elseif-else` from the beginning saves you edits in the future, and is clearer to people reading your code.

These days to write a program is not a big task whereas the **maintainabililty** of the code is the major requirement. Because of the the chaning world and there requirements, We are required to update or change the code time to time. Thus it is very much required to indent the code for better **readability**.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't want to return something this looks fine to me.
Otherwise you could use the one-liner if.

```
return (<statemen>) ? <handles true> : <handles false>;
```

I am not sure if it is working in PHP too, but it is surely working with javascript.

Comment: The `()` around the `<statement>` is not required, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that is usually quite useful when you try to minimise the indentation in your script files. There are generally no problems with it.

The only problem that could possibly arise is if you want to add an `else` block to your functions. With the former syntax, it'd be a simple addition of `else` to the end of it. If you're using `return` instead, that'd be impossible, and you'd have to convert it to the former syntax.

This applies to both PHP and JavaScript. It also applies to most languages that have a similar kind of syntax.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of Javascript this should do no harm at all since javascript functions return *undefined* either way. (you writing *return;* or not)

For PHP I'm not really sure, but I can't imagine any problems right now.

**But** I would think of this as bad practice since indentation helps to see what's going on.
If you have many of those checks in one function, maybe you should think about creating more, smaller functions instead of one big function, because this too, helps reading your code.